# Android's Intent for ACTION_CALL just dials

Tags: android, android-intent

Just like the title says, I've tested that many times with no changes in several devices but customers still mention that it only dials, they sit there in the dialer app with the number on screen but they have to press the 'call' button to make it. I believe few of the models are Samsung and it goes from 2.3.x to 4.0.x.

Why's that?? It's driving me crazy and also I don't even use the `ACTION_DIAL` intent action.

Here's the code:

```
private void call(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    context.startActivity(call);
}
```

Permission's there, and the phone number is valid because it's shown in the dial screen as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest trying to come up with an exact device model (preferably using the model name, rather than just a marketing term like "Galaxy S4") that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Also note that the user may need to tap something to place the call, to choose between different dialing options. For example, my Nexus 4 is set up with two VOIP options and standard mobile telephony, and I have to choose which one to use for placing the call. Most users will not have that.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked for the model and this possible behavior and nothing shows up on Google. I have a feeling it has to do with a faulty implementation of Twilio (VoIP call that might be ongoing) and the system knows that if notified by Twilio. Leading to dialing instead of calling. That's my hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's the expected behaviour. In my opinion that's a security feature so applications will not auto dial numbers where the customer will pay extra charges for example. This way he can still change his mind even if the app had permission to start the dialler.

So far I've never seen a phone that automatically dials it.

Comment: "As far as I know that's the expected behaviour" -- um, no. `ACTION_DIAL` would have this behavior. `ACTION_CALL` is supposed to place the call, which is why the permission is there. "So far I've never seen a phone that automatically dials it" -- which ones have you tried? It worked fine just now on a Nexus 4, the first device that I tried.

Comment: My bad! I just checked the code and indeed, it's ACTION_DIAL that has this behaviour. Sorry for the confusion.